# gdb core file truncated httpd with php

Tags: php, debugging, gdb, apache

I am trying to analyze a core dump from a LAMP setup. It says the core was truncated, and the only information is that it got a segfault, which already is reported in the httpd error log. I can't get a full backtrace or step through.

I installed symbols for httpd and freetds (sql server driver), php did not have debug headers from what I could find. Do I even need all of the symbols for all of the httpd modules, or just httpd itself?

How can I get a good core that has some information in it?

```
BFD: Warning: /tmp/core.10242 is truncated: expected core file size >= 576610304, found: 11689984.
BFD: Warning: /tmp/core.10242 is truncated: expected core file size >= 576610304, found: 11689984.
[New Thread 10242]
[New Thread 10753]
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002aaaac7f8b60 in ?? ()
"/tmp/core.10242" is a core file.
Please specify an executable to debug.
```

Comment: what is the output of `ulimit -a`?